# Does the R hts-Package work with time series of different units?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

currently I'm having a look at the wonderful [hts-Package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hts/index.html). Its idea is to forecast hierarchical time series (like described [here](https://otexts.com/fpp2/hts.html)). In [this example](https://otexts.com/fpp2/reconciliation.html) the unit of measurement across all time series is the same, e.g. people.

Does this approach (especially the `combinef`-Function in optimal reconciliation mode) also works for mixed unit time series? I'm thinking for example of weather-data where the temperature of one time series is measured in C° and of another in F° (same quantity, different unit). Or even more complex: Currency in different countries with daily changing exchange rates.

Aggregating such data would at least render the level 0 result useless, but does it work on the level 1, assuming that all levels below 1 use the same unit (e.g. $ or F°)?